# Get latest value for each ID in Power BI / DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I would like to create a DAX **measure** that will retrieve the latest string value for specific IDs. **Example source table:**

```
Name_ID  |   Name      |      DateTime         |    Value
----------------------------------------------------------
1        |   Child_1   |  18.8.2021 12:33:24   |     F
32       |   Parent_32 |  18.8.2021 11:41:09   |     F
13       |   Child_1   |  18.8.2021 11:30:58   |     E
48       |   Parent_48 |  18.8.2021 09:13:11   |     F
2        |   Child_2   |  17.8.2021 00:09:42   |     S
1        |   Child_1   |  17.8.2021 23:03:34   |     F
48       |   Parent_48 |  17.8.2021 21:46:27   |     S
6        |   Parent_6  |  16.8.2021 17:31:26   |     S 
.
.
.
```

specific parents IDs for example here are 6, 32 and 48, so **the result should be something like this:**

```
Name_ID    |    Name      |     DateTime (of last execution)  |  Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
32         |   Parent_32  |       18.8.2021 11:41:09          |     F
48         |   Parent_48  |       18.8.2021 09:13:11          |     F
6          |   Parent_6   |       16.8.2021 17:31:26          |     S
```

The result table I'm trying to get is only parents latest appearance and retrieving the whole row or just Value from last column.
This seems so easy in theory and on paper but I just can't seem to get it in DAX I have tried with various calculate formulas but without any result worth mentioning .

I'm beginner in Power Bi and any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you remove all unnecessary columns and row of your sample data, so that the sample data matches your expected results table? I guess that you group by Name column and then you make a self left join to it? Or you remove all the rows with Child from it? Perhaps you may write SQL query, so that it will be easier to write DAX equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a measure like this one, where we check Max Date per Name:

```
Flag = 

var MaxDatePerName = CALCULATE(max(Sheet3[DateTime]), FILTER(ALL(Sheet3), SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[Name]) = Sheet3[Name]))
return

if( MaxDatePerName = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[DateTime]) && LEFT(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet3[Name]),6) = "Parent", 1, BLANK())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `RANKX`

```
Measure2 =
VAR _0 =
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[DateTime] )
VAR _00 =
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Name] )
VAR _1 =
    CALCULATE (
        RANKX (
            FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table 1' ), 'Table 1'[Name] = _00 ),
            CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table 1'[DateTime] ) ),
            ,
            DESC
        )
    )
VAR _2 =
    IF ( _1 = 1 && CONTAINSSTRING ( _00, "Parent" ) = TRUE (), _0, BLANK () )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]